# Can't access variable from different class

Tags: ios, swift, global, cllocationmanager

I am in the process of updating my app to Swift 2.0, however I have ran into an issue with `CLLocationManager`.

I have used this code for a while, so I am slightly puzzled as to why it has suddenly became an issue in 2.0. I am using a global variable (lazy, I know), but it doesn't seem to be accessible in any other class other than the one it was declared in. I am getting this error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'locationManager'

This is the code I have in the class where I'm declaring `locationManager`:

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

class InitalViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            //Requests location use from user for maps
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code in the other class:

```
@IBAction func centerOnLocation(sender: AnyObject) {
    if locationManager.location != nil {
        let locationCamera = MKMapCamera()
        locationCamera.heading = parkPassed.orientation!
        locationCamera.altitude = 600
        locationCamera.centerCoordinate.latitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
        locationCamera.centerCoordinate.longitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude

        mapView.setCamera(locationCamera, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement an extension of `CLLocationManager` to use an instance as singleton.

```
extension CLLocationManager{

  class var sharedManager : CLLocationManager {
    struct Singleton {
      static let instance = CLLocationManager()
    }
    return Singleton.instance
  }
}
```

then you can access the singleton in any class

```
@IBAction func centerOnLocation(sender: AnyObject) {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager.sharedManager
    if locationManager.location != nil {
        let locationCamera = MKMapCamera()
        locationCamera.heading = parkPassed.orientation!
        locationCamera.altitude = 600
        locationCamera.centerCoordinate.latitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
        locationCamera.centerCoordinate.longitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude

        mapView.setCamera(locationCamera, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Default access level for globals is now `internal`, as in internal to all the source files in the same module. If `centerOnLocation` is in a different module, you need to add the `public` modifier to the definition of your global:

```
public var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

Comment: I had wondered if this might be the case, but I still get the same error unfortunately.